# I cannot add an element to list property. VS says, that there is not set reference to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add an element from entry to a list property in viewmodel, using button. The viewmodel file is imported correctly (It whispers me the properties). I know, that there is some simple mistake, but I didn't figure it out.

```
//View part

//using the file with vm classes
using Pichacka.ViewModel;

//making an instance
viewmodel vm = new viewmodel();

private void BtnAddCertainFirm_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entFirmName.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entFirmMoney.
   {
      App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR", "Nezadal jste všechny hodnoty!", "OK");
   }
   else
   {            
       string jmenoFirmy = entFirmName.Text; //getting the string value from entry
       //string penizeFirmy = entFirmMoney.Text; this line is not importatnt for this problem

       vm.listFirem.Add(jmenoFirmy); //here im trying to add an element
   }
}

//ViewModel part


//list property itself..
private List<string> _listFirem;

public List<string> listFirem
{
   get { return _listFirem; }
   set { _listFirem = value; }
}
```

Expected results: Clicking the button will add new element into the list property

Actual results: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an instance of viewmodel only and not of `listFirem` property. Its default value will be `null` when you create an instance of `viewmodel`. Therefore when you try to add an element to this list, you will get the null reference exception.

To resolve this, initialize the `listFirem` property with an instance of `List<string>`. Like this:

```
viewmodel vm = new viewmodel();
vm.listFirem = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,as akg179's reply, you'll need to ensure that the collection isn't null and is properly instantiated prior to adding an object to it.

```
public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{

    public Page5 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
    viewmodel vm = new viewmodel();
    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vm.listfirm = new List<string>();

        vm.listfirm.Add("test");
    }
}
public class viewmodel
{
    public List<string> listfirm { get; set; }
}
```